# "sample" vs "specimen" in a scientific document on condensed matter physics

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I am searching for an appropriate headline in scientific document. The chapter is named "Investigated Specimen" at the moment. In the chapter I describe crystals that I have investigated.

I feel that "Investigated Specimen" is not clear or appropriately descriptive.  Would "Samples Used in the Experiments" be a common title or is there perhaps a better variant that is used in scientific papers?

Comment: How about "crystals under investigation"?

Comment: Have you looked at published papers in your field?

Comment: You'll get a more relevant answer on physics.stackexchange.com.  Jargon varies greatly between fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Experimental Samples** is a possibility. **Analyzed Samples** is another. I don't like *specimen*, even though it's a perfectly reasonable synonym, because it makes me think of *urine specimen* and *stool specimen* (I'm a biomedical editor), and I think that **sample** is more general in current scientific usage: many biomed, business management, and other technical writers use **sample size** to refer to the number of specimens in their study populations, whether they be rats, humans, tissue samples, data points, etc.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you have used "sample" as an attributive noun when the OP used it as a simple noun. **Sample size** usually refers to the number of those things in the sample, whereas **specimen size** refers to the dimensions of that actual specimen. -- *because it makes me think of urine specimen and stool specimen* -- Could you please explain what your squeamishness has to do with the English language?

Answer (score 2):

I have come upon this exchange because I too need to choose between "sample" and "specimen" in a manuscript describing biological collections. I think there is an important difference, as a specimen is an example of an individual and a sample would contain multiple individuals (specimens) collected from a site. I don't worry that "specimen" might describe a cup of urine or a pinned insect, what is important is that specimen and sample are not interchangeable in this context. A sample of specimens represents a portion of a population from which biologists will attempt to extrapolate information.

Answer (score 1):

A specimen is of minute size ready to fit into the analyzing system and may contain multiple individuals as well e.g.in a malarial stained slide you may as well observe other micro-organisms that are not plasmodium; but the sample is the primary source of the specimen or the representative of the population from which the specimen has been extracted.

Answer (score 0):

I used the linux command 
`find -name "*.pdf" -exec pdftotext '{}' - \; |egrep --colour sample | wc -l`
to make a statistic on the usage of `specimen` and `sample` in publications of nature, and physic journals.

Files scanned: 443

`specimen` occured 57 times

`sample` occured 1696 times

Hence I am convinced to use `sample`

Comment: I'd agree that *sample* is the right word to use (I'd use *specimen* for animals and plants, or parts thereof, and *sample* for inanimate material) but your statistics here are very likely misleading, because they do not distinguish between the word *sample* used as a verb and a noun. Possibly you should do a comparison between "the specimens" and "the samples" (plural to avoid things like "the sample size").